# Spark - SparkSession - Cannot Import

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to import SparkSession using Pyspark from Anaconda spider and Pyspark Command Line but getting below error. I have given the details of the versions that i have installed in my machine.

```
Error : ImportError: cannot import name 'SparkSession' from 'pyspark' (E:\spark3\python\pyspark\__init__.py).
```

Assist me to resolve this issue

Spark Version :

[image]

Python Version

[image]

pyspark

[image]

Error From Spyder

[image]

Error From Pyspark Command Line

[image]

My Environmental Variable setup

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although it has been a long time since you asked your question, I think you aim to use pyspark.sql so by this way you should import:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```